# Xampp folder not opening properly

Tags: php, xampp

I'm clueless as to why this is happening but I'm not able to open my PHP file.

I tried to use another folder but same error occurs.

I have saved the file in XAMPP's htdocs folder.

[image]

Comment: Have you started the sever?

Comment: I'm not sure where is the problem, you are not accessing any PHP file, XAMPP is showing you a directory, and from the URL, that's the right thing to show...

Comment: What happens when you click on var1.php?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the .php file is not named index.php, apache will not open it by default when navigating to the project's directory.

Clicking on it, will open it manually. Do you get an error when opening it manually?

For example, a **var1.php** file that contains the following line:

```
<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>
```

will print the following if php is running properly

> hello world

and the following if php is **not** running  properly

> php echo 'hello world';